# X10Hosting Password Protect Pages

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, redirect

## SOLVED

<strike>My question is *how* can I password protect *not* folders, but also **files** (pages). It only allows me to password protect folders, and I either want to be able to use like a php feature for it to redirect to a login page if you go to it and the current password/username that I set is correct, then it will *again* redirect you *back* to the page that was originally protected, or just use a simple feature that I'm not aware of to redirect it to a login page.</strike>

## Things I've Already Tried

- Redirect Feature offered by x10Hosting

  - Can't use because going back to it will automatically redirect it back to the login page; causing a infinite loop.
- Putting it in a folder and accessing it from there

  - I have a secret page featuring upcoming events and projects, hidden pages, and more for teachers and classmates. Password protecting a folder will only access it by viewing a index, which none of them hold the capability nor intelligence to figure out how to operate. Plus, I would have to create a seperate FTP account, which they also don't know how to operate.

## Things to Note

- I used to have a system where it uses .aspx extension pages and had a `<? ?>` (php I assume) open/close tags before the `<html>` on both a `login.aspx` page and the `secret.aspx` page itself, but now migrating from my old web host to x10Hosting, it reads .aspx files as a text document, causing it to open up AS a text document on load, so I can't use .aspx extensions which I *THINK* (is the only one that) doesn't support the `<?` tags, causing it to just appear as text above the page. I have since lost that code.
- I'd like it to be able to have a simple login form on a seperate page, whereas going to the secret page directly will redirect it to the `login.?` page, which you put in a password & username that I set, and if correct will redirect you automatically to the secret page on a button click (`<input type="submit">`) I'd assume.

Comment: sidenote: `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .aspx` in your `.htaccess` should allow the execution of PHP within `.aspx` files. But, I don't know about X10's restrictions.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the fact of allowing PHP execution; it's the fact of it not even loading as html but as a "text/x-generic" file type, loading nothing but the code itself, @Ohgodwhy

Comment: That's because there's no interpter to parse .aspx extensions created and apache will not attempt to parse it by default, so therefore it gets `x-generic` applied through the default settings. give my suggestion a go?

Comment: Sure thing; I'll edit this comment as soon as I get results.

#EDIT
Working fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED; FIGURED IT OUT

With the help of @Ohgodwhy, I managed to get my old system back. Using PhP, I used the following code for my secret page;

```
<%
Validated = "OK"
if Request.Cookies("ValidUser") <> Validated then
'Construct the URL for the current page.
    dim s
    s = "http://"
    s = s & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")
    s = s & Request.ServerVariables("URL")
    if Request.QueryString.Count > 0 THEN
    s = s & "?" & Request.QueryString 
    end if
    'Redirect unauthorized users to the logon page.
    Response.Redirect "Logon.asp?from=" &Server.URLEncode(s)
End if
%>
<html>
...
</html>
```

Then I used the following code for the logon page;

```
<%
Username="[insert]"
Password="[insert]"
Validated = "OK"
if Strcomp(Request.Form("User"),Username,1)=0 AND Request.Form("password") = Password then
'Set the validation cookie and redirect the user to the original page.
    Response.Cookies("ValidUser") = Validated
    'Check where the users are coming from within the application.
    If (Request.QueryString("from")<>"") then
    Response.Redirect Request.QueryString("from")
    else
    'If the first page that the user accessed is the Logon page,
        'direct them to the default page.
          Response.Redirect "secret.aspx"
    End if    
Else
' Only present the failure message if the user typed in something.
    If Request.Form("User") <> "" then
        Response.Write "<h3>Authorization Failed.</h3>" & "<br>" & _
        "Please try again.<br>&#xa0;<br>"
    End if
End if
%>
...
<div id="body">
<form action=<%Response.Write "LogonSecurity.asp?"&Request.QueryString%> method="post">
<h3>Login</h3>
<p> 
Username: 
<input type="text" name="User" placeholder="Username" value='' size="20"></input>
Password: 
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value='' size="20"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Logon"></input>
</form>
</div>
...
</html>
```